# how can i pass an array outside its loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I have this written in a sub in vba, but I have no idea of how to get  *final_array*  outside of the loop. I would like to either transpose to the sheet or save to a global multidimensional array.

```
Dim lent As Long
Dim end_ct As Long


end_ct = 0

Dim final_array() As Variant
ReDim Preserve final_array(11)


final_array(0) = Range("B2").value
final_array(1) = Range("B3").value

j = 8
'Debug.Print final_array(0)
'Debug.Print final_array(1)

For lent = 2 To 11 Step 1


    If lent Mod 2 = 0 Then

        ReDim Preserve final_array(11)
        final_array(lent) = end_pt(end_ct) - strt_pt(end_ct)

        end_ct = end_ct + 1
        'Sheets("SingleEquityHistoryHedge").Cells(47, lent + 1).value = final_array(lent)
    Else

        'gets average over pattern period
        Dim avg_rng As Range
        Set avg_rng = Sheets("SingleEquityHistoryHedge").Range(Cells(strt_pt(end_ct), j), Cells(end_pt(end_ct) - 1, j))
        'Debug.Print sum_rng
        Dim avg_value As Double
        avg_value = avgVal(avg_rng)

        ReDim Preserve final_array(11)
        final_array(lent) = avg_value

       ' Sheets("SingleEquityHistoryHedge").Cells(47, lent + 2).FormulaArray = _
       ' "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & avg_rng.Address & ")," & avg_rng.Address & "))"

        j = j + 1
    End If




   ' Debug.Print final_array(lent)
'    Debug.Print final_array

'    If lent = 11 Then
'        Range("A" & pos).Select
'        Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose (final_array)
'    End If

Next lent
```

My goal is to be able to print final_array outside of the loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's not working?  Since you declare final_array before the start of the loop you should be able to access it just fine after the loop.

Comment: when i try an use Debug.Print final_array or Application.Transpose(final_array) it doesnt return anything.... I printed all the individual elements of the array so I know the values are there, just not sure why I cant transpose it outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked your code whether it is populating the array or not but if it is then after the loop you can write that array to any cell by using this (*I am using A1 as an example*)

```
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(final_array) + 1, 1) = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(final_array)
```